# How to save the userdetails when click on checkbox in wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need to save the username ,password text when click on remember me checkbox.if whenever checkbox is checked the user again login then need to show saved values in that textboxes.if unchecked the remember me checkbox then don't need to show the details when he is login.Again need to enter his name,password texts to login.please tell me....

Answer (score 0):

You try yourself something and ask us if you stuck somewhere.

Check this link for a good example on how to store and retrieve the settings in the [IsolatedStorageSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Use the Checked event handler of checkbox to store the data in the IsolatedStorage and Unchecked handler to remove it from IsolatedStorage.

And each time you show the login boxes, check for the availability of the Data in IsolatedStorage and render accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Bind your username and password to properties in the viewModel and make viewModel extract this data from isolated storage.